# Serving js and css files using assetic in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Below is my code:

```
<head>
    {% stylesheets debug=true
           '@PractoPvrBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css'
           '@PractoPvrBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}
</head>
```

I get following error

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"Route \"_assetic_4fec32d_0\" does not exist.\
```

Need help with this. I'm following the docs and am not able to figure out the error.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the cache?

Comment: yes. twice. It's not working :(

Comment: Also try to check the output of `php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev --no-debug`.

Comment: Check that you have routing set for assetic

Comment: Yep. I didn't have assetic routing configured correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error messages seems to be one of those which hides the real reason it comes up. This means there can be multiple solution which may or may not work.

For those who came across the message the same way as me, this is the cause and solution:

**Cause:**
Your twig file calls a js/css/image via assetic using "{{ asset_url }} but the file isn't there for whatever reason.
You go make sure the fire is there.
You reload the page and you see the error above.

**Solution:**
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev

Generally wise to run this as www-data. I have had issues running as any other user.

This is obviously not the cause or solution for the original poster, but for people like me with the same error message that found this post, I hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you forget to include your bundle to assetic's configuration or forget to comment out `bundles` settings:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    #bundles:        [ ]
```